# AlertDialog not displaying file list

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder load_alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            File list = new File("data/data/project/databases/");
            if(!list.exists() || !list.isDirectory()){
                return;
            }
            String [] fileList = list.list();

            load_alert.setMessage("Please select");     
            load_alert.setItems(fileList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }); 
            load_alert.show();
```

This is supposed to display the content of my database folder into an alertdialog.  I've checked the fileList array, and it is being populated.  For some reason it just isn't displaying via setItems.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

I realize I'm a little late to the ballgame and that you have probably already solved your problem, but I was having the same issue and I figured out what the problem was.

Apparently, when you call `.setMessage()`, that overrides the `setItems()` declaration and turns the `AlertDialog` into a message dialog. Instead, call `.setTitle()` to set the title of the dialog.

Also, in your example you don't seem to call `.create()`, so it should be `load_alert.create().show()`. Presumably that's a transcription error, though, because I think `AlertDialog.Builder` doesn't have a `show()` method.

Comment: I've just had the same problem .. the API docs really should specify the difference between both calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even I am late in posting
but here is what i tried and was able to display all the folders.

```
AlertDialog.Builder listAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        String [] filelist = path.list();
        listAlert.setTitle("Select Definition File");
        listAlert.setItems(filelist, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Stuffs to do after you have selected folder or file.

        }
    }).show();
```

and at some point in my code i have

```
private File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"");
```

Thanks